# how to create an associative array from database object and json_encode as object instead of array?

Tags: php, arrays, json, yii

I am a newbie in PHP and developing an app using Yii. I have a database object where all I got all the records of a table. I wanted to create an associative array from that object and later encode that array in json_encode. However, my desired output,which is objects instead of array, is not coming. can anyone help, plz?
My code:

```
$info = array();
$category = Category::find()->all();
foreach($category as $key => $value) {
    $info[]=  array(
         "name" =>$value->name,
         "value" =>$value->description  
    ) ;
} 
echo json_encode($info,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

**Output**:

```
{"0":{"name":"test","value":"A"},"1":{"name":"test 2","value":"B"}}
```

**Desired Output**:

```
{"category":[{"name":"test","value":"A"},{"name":"test 2","value":"B"}]}
```

Comment: The undesired output is caused by the `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` flag.

Comment: The latter is not valid JSON. An array of anonymous objects needs to be stored in `"[]"` - Valid output would be `{"info":[{"name":"test","value":"A"},{"name":"test 2","value":"B"}]}`. It should be extremely easy to parse the existing output, though. Each object is correctly encoded, it is just mapped to the original array index.

Comment: @SteveK you're right, just looked through my requirements. I have just edited the question. Can you take a look and tell me how to do it, plz?

Comment: thanks everybody, I just have found what I  was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
$info2['category']=$info;
echo json_encode($info2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array_values() before json_encode

```
$info =  array_values($info);
echo json_encode($info,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```